# Does PDFBox Support Spot Colors and Separations?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, color-space

I am interested in using PDFBox for a project that requires being able to specify spot colors and color separations in PDF output to go to a professional printer and am curious as to whether or not it supports this. If so (and I think so), I am also looking for some example code.

I found an old post from 2009 on their mailing list ([here](http://pdfbox.markmail.org/message/rdasgh4k6ivei3v3?q=color%20separation)) that leads me to believe PDFBox can support color separations, but have not succeeded in finding any example code. I looked through their [JavaDoc](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/) and discovered the `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color` classes, but don't have any idea how to leverage them and don't see any [cookbook](http://pdfbox.apache.org/userguide/cookbook.html) examples on their website or in their source code.

I specifically would appreciate any examples that help illustrate the DeviceN colorspace.

Comment: Seperation and DeviceN isn''t the same.

Answer (score 2):

Please see as below

[image]

1. get the PDColor from a PDF file(spotColor.pdf),and make sure that the spot colors which you well used are in this PDF file.(I made the file by Adobe Illustrator)

   ```
       public static Map<String, PDColor> getSpotColor() {
           Map<String, PDColor> colors = new HashMap<String, PDColor>();
           PDDocument spotColorFile = null;
           try {
               spotColorFile = PDDocument.load(new FileInputStream(new File(
                       "d:\\spotColor.pdf")));
               for (PDPage page : spotColorFile.getPages()) {
                   for (COSName name : page.getResources().getColorSpaceNames()) {
                       PDColor color = page.getResources().getColorSpace(name)
                               .getInitialColor();
                       PDSeparation cs = (PDSeparation) color.getColorSpace();
                       colors.put(cs.getColorantName(), color);
                   }
               }
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } finally {
               if (spotColorFile != null)
                   try {
                       spotColorFile.close();
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   } finally {
                       spotColorFile = null;
                   }
           }
           return colors;
       }
   ```
2. use your PDColor

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       PDDocument doc = null;
       PDPage page = null;
       try {
           Map<String, PDColor> colors = getSpotColor();
           doc = new PDDocument();
           page = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(100, 100));
           doc.addPage(page);
           PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);

           content.beginText();
           content.setNonStrokingColor(colors.get("PANTONE 2607 C"));
           content.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 20);
           content.showText("abcdef");
           content.endText();

           content.setNonStrokingColor(colors.get("PANTONE 108 U"));
           content.addRect(50, 50, 50, 50);
           content.fill();
           content.close();

           doc.save("d:\\spotColorTest.pdf");
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e);
       } finally {
           if (doc != null)
               try {
                   doc.close();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               } finally {
                   doc = null;
               }
       }
   }
   ```

3 if you have some idea more smarter, please let me know
  :)

Comment: Your answer would help the OP more if you explained the code to him.

Comment: This line `PDSeparation cs = (PDSeparation) color.getColorSpace();` is risky because you can't know for sure that all colors are separation. Besides that, I think the answer is OK; the alternative would be to create the colorspace from scratch which is difficult because the tintTransform function has to be created.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use `PDSeparation` [class](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/color/PDSeparation.html)

Comment: This seems like it is a step in the right direction. Do you have any sample code for applying this class to PDF output?